# How to send whole flattened data from Javascript file of LWC to Apex method?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am building upon [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292598/how-to-send-flattened-data-from-javascript-file-of-lwc-to-apex-method).

In that question, the solution for sending one field from LWC's JS file to apex class was given. I want to return the complete data, what datatype do I use to hold the data in apex? Please help. Thanks!

This is how I send the data from JS file to apex:

```js
let selected = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').getSelectedRows();
        if (selected.length > 0) {
            del({ deleteIds: selected })
                .then(result => { //...
                 }
                .catch(error => { //...
                 }
        }
```

The data that I need to return from JS file is a javascript object in this form:

```
Selected:[{"Contact_Role":"User Contact", "Account_Id":"0015400000Nmy5PAAR", "Contact_Id":"0035400000LHBGLAA5", "Account_Name":"Yahoo Inc Taiwan", "Account_MDM_Id":"10009899", "Is_Primary":false, "CRId":"a0854000002jBoRAAU"},
{"Contact_Role":"Legal", "Account_Id":"0013200000Nmy2DDSX", "Contact_Id":"0035400000LHBGLAA5", "Account_Name":"Razor Corp", "Account_MDM_Id":"10334424", "Is_Primary":false, "CRId":"a0859000003jBoQRRF"}]
```

How do I hold this data in apex? I tried these things but they don't work:

```js
@AuraEnabled 
    public static void del(Map<String,String> deleteIds) {
    //gives null value for deleteIds
}

@AuraEnabled 
    public static void del(String[] deleteIds) {
    //gives error "Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'deleteIds' of type 'List'"
}
```

Please guide me as to what datatype I should use to hold the data in apex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `List<Map<String, Object>>`:

```
@AuraEnabled 
    public static void del(List<Map<String, Object>> deleteIds) {

    }
```

You can tell because the JSON is in the form of:

```
[{...},{...}]
```

Where

```
[...]
```

Is an array, and

```
{...}
```

Is an object.

Comment: If "{...}" is an object then what is the key in Map<String, Object> deleteIds?

Comment: @Koustubh `Contact_Role`, `Account_Id`, etc. The top-level element is a list.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox that's very helpful. Can it also be represented as List<Map<String, String>> ?

Comment: @Koustubh You have the attribute `"Is_Active":true`, which would be a Boolean value, so, without changing your data, you couldn't use a String value type.