# Pass list <String> from apex to LWC datatable Columns

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lwc-wire-adapter

Greeting for the day,
I have a requirement where I want to pass Event's relatedto Contacts name to lightning web component and show in a datatable, From apex class, I am able get list of contacts name , but in Lwc I am not getting names in datatable

Apex code:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<String> fetchActivity(){
      List<String> whoNameList = new List<String>();
        List<Event> activityList= [select id,WhoId,Subject,who.name from Event where StartDateTime= TODAY and CreatedById=: userInfo.getUserId() ];
      system.debug('activity'+activityList);
       for( Event ev :ctivityList){
          
          whoNameList.add(ev.who.name);
       }
       system.debug(whoNameList);
 
        return whoNameList;
    }
```

LWC JS:

```
import  fetchActivity from "@salesforce/apex/checkInOutClass.fetchActivity";
```

```
   @track eventList ;
   data = [];
   @track columns = [{
       label: 'Client to Vist',
        fieldName: 'Who.name',
       type: 'text'
   }];

@wire(fetchActivity)
   
    wiredAcitvity({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
           
            this.eventList = data;
           // this.columns = data.columns;
          //  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

LWC HTML:

```
  <div style="height: 300px; width: 50%;" class="slds-float_left" >
                <template if:true={eventList}>
                    <lightning-datatable data={eventList} columns={columns} key-field="Id" hide-checkbox-column="true"  >
                    </lightning-datatable>
                    
                </template>
                <template if:true={error}>
                    {error}
                </template>
            </div>
```

This is just part of my code
Please help Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        this.eventList = data;
```

`eventList` is (well, in Apex) a `List<String>`. In JavaScript, it's an array of string values.

```
   @track columns = [{
       label: 'Client to Vist',
        fieldName: 'Who.name',
       type: 'text'
   }];
```

You are telling LWC that your data is a list of *objects* with a key called `Who.name`. That is not true. Your data is not a list of objects, and does not have a key `Who.name`.

You'll need to postprocess your data in JavaScript to turn the flat array into an array of objects (using a `for` loop or a `forEach()` or `map()` construct) and set the string value as a specific property on each object. The name of that property will then be the value of `fieldName` in your `columns` definition.

Something like

```
this.eventList = data.map((s) => ({ myKey: s });
```

should do the trick.

---

I will also note that there are multiple misspellings and case mistakes in this code. In this case, they're not the proximate cause of your problem, but you *must* be careful to spell identifiers correctly and use the correct casing (in JavaScript), or your code may exhibit unexpected behaviors or fail to compile.

Comment: I am new to LWC and not so good in JS, trying to understand , can you please be specific on where and what should I do

Comment: What, specifically, do you need more support on?

Comment: Another Method I tried to get who.Name of Contacts on Event object , passing List<Event> (passing id, name, whoId,who.name) from apex to LWC , but when accessing the values in columns I was able to retrieve all fields except who.name, actually I needed contacts name instead of ID

Comment: As you said , passing values in for loop , I have pass who.name as list<string> what will be its field name while using in loop , for eg : list<Event> we access like 
            for(let i=0; i<this.eventList.length; i++){
                console.log(this.eventList[i].Name);
            }

Comment: As I say above, a list of strings does not have field names. That's why you would convert this list into a list of objects, which do have field names.

Comment: There are a number of existing questions about flattening related data (Object.Field) for use in data tables. See [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287262/flatten-data-to-display-it-using-lightning-datatable-in-lwc) question in particular.

Comment: Got it, Thanks buddy