# Not able to display Lookup data to lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-datatable

I am not able to display Lookup data on a data-table - contact__r.Phone. I have tried following [Flatten data to display it using lightning datatable in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287262/flatten-data-to-display-it-using-lightning-datatable-in-lwc) to create a prepared list for the datatable columns, but no luck.

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getLog from '@salesforce/apex/FridgeLogsController.getLog';

const columns = [
    {label: 'Timestamp', fieldName: 'LastModifiedDate', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Employee Name', fieldName: 'employeeName__c', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Fridge ID', fieldName: 'fridgeId__c', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Phone #', fieldName: 'contactPhone', type: 'phone'},
];

export default class ExerciseTrigger extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns;
    log;

    @wire(getLog) logList(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            // this.log = result.data;
            this.error = undefined;

            let preparedArr = [];
            result.data.forEach(record => {
                let preparedRec = {};
                preparedRec.LastModifiedDate = record.LastModifiedDate;
                preparedRec.employeeName__c = record.employeeName__c;
                preparedRec.fridgeId__c = record.fridgeId__c;
                preparedRec.contactPhone = record.contact__r.Phone;

                preparedArr.push(preparedRec);
            });
            this.log = preparedArr;
            
        } else if (result.data) {
            this.log = result.error;
            this.error = undefined;
        } 
    }
}
```

With `preparedRec.contactPhone = record.contact__r.Phone;`, I get a completely blank data-table.
If I comment it out, I get all the columns data except for the Phone#.

HTML:

```
    <template>
    <lightning-card title="Fridge Log" icon-name="standard:service_territory"> 
        <!-- Lightning datatable -->
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium" style="height: 300px;">
            <template if:true={log}>
                <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={log}
                    columns={columns}
                    hide-checkbox-column="true">
                </lightning-datatable>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

CLS:

```
public with sharing class FridgeLogsController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Fridge_Logs__c> getLog() {
        return [
            SELECT LastModifiedDate, employeeName__c, fridgeId__c, contact__r.Phone
            FROM Fridge_Logs__c
            ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC
        ];
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger FridgeTrigger on Fridge_Log__e (after insert) {
    // List to insert
    list<Fridge_Logs__c> dataToInsert = new List<Fridge_Logs__c>();
    
    for (Fridge_Log__e event : Trigger.New) {
        System.debug('Data ID from emitter: ' + event.badgeId__c);
        // Record to add
        Fridge_Logs__c data = new Fridge_Logs__c();
        // Store event into variable for storing
        data.badgeId__c = event.badgeId__c;
        data.employeeName__c = event.employeeName__c;
        data.fridgeId__c = event.fridgeId__c;
        List<Contact> lookupList = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = :data.employeeName__c ];
        data.Contact__c = lookupList[0].Id;
        dataToInsert.add(data);
        
        if(!dataToInsert.isEmpty()){
            // Record data in db
            insert dataToInsert;
        } 
    }
}
```

Query results are displaying the Phone#:
[image]

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten data to display it using lightning datatable in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287262/flatten-data-to-display-it-using-lightning-datatable-in-lwc)

Comment: I followed the answer there and got no luck, I'm not sure what I am missing here

Comment: I am getting an error here:
preparedRec.contactPhone = record.contact__r.Phone;
  


SELECT LastModifiedDate, employeeName__c, fridgeId__c, contact__r.Phone
            FROM Fridge_Logs__c
            ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC

Comment: I would change `log;` to `@track log = [];` and then change `this.log = preparedArr;` to `this.log = [...preparedArr];`

Comment: And yes, unlike Apex, Javascript is case sensitive, so you need to `record.Contact__r.Phone` (capital C)

Comment: @zaitsman Im getting results in dev console using lower case contact__r.Phone, so I assume in Javascript would use lower case too. Either way I m getting this error in js file: [contact__r is not defined]  or [Contact__r is not defined]

Comment: @ApexCowboy don't assume. The dev console uses query api which has nothing to do with your Apex code. Perhaps that specific object has no Contact? try
`preparedRec.contactPhone = record.Contact__r?.Phone;`

Comment: @zaitsman I tried all combinations of upper and lower cases for both js and cls files, and still getting not defined error for contact__r. I looked into the records and it has "Contact" data there. I looked into the Fields and Relationship for Fridge Log, there is: Contact, Contact__c, Lookup(Contact)

Comment: @ApexCowboy what does your networking tool in the browser show?

Comment: @zaitsman Which part in Network am I looking at? Im in Chrome Inspect's Network tab and it says 59requests, Finished 12.00sec. The console says exerciseTrigger.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: LWC component's '@'wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[contact__r is not defined]
    at eval (exerciseTrigger.js:4).

I switched to Uppercase for both cls and js files, and I still get [Contact__r is not defined] from chrome's inspect console

Comment: @zaitsman If I replace the line with preparedRec.contactPhone = '199'; it would show 199 in Phone column and works. But if I put preparedRec.contactPhone = Contact__r.Phone; the data-table won't even show at all

Comment: @zaitsman OK SOLVED. It needed record.Contract__r.Phone and I missed the "record." Geez thank you very much, Im sure the uppercase part helped.

Comment: @ApexCowboy Also, be sure to add ```preparedRec.Id = record.Id;``` in the JS, and Id in the SOQL query, if you want to handle any table interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Solved,
preparedRec.contactPhone = *record*.**Contact__r**.Phone;

Adjustment: Uppercase